# Codeigniter Array in GET variable Clean URL

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, get

I would like to ask if there is any option how to change URL with Array in GET to CLEAN.

Example:

From this: example.com/school/4/**?city[]=1&city[]=2&city[]=3**
I need this: example.com/school/4/**?city=1,2,3**

*(I use Codeigniter framework.)*

I was thinking about mod_rewrite but I'm unable to do it.
I would really appreciate your help here.
Thank you.

// To explain it more:
**I need to change first mentioned url to second one.**

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's going to come in in that format, you could just do:

```
$_GET['city'] = explode(",", $_GET['city']);
```

The only problem you will run into is when a value actually contains a comma.

If you need to get your form to actually submit it that way, it's a different problem.  I'll assume you are using jQuery for simplicities sake, but you could do:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
   var cities = '';
   $('[name="city"]').each(function() {
        cities = cities + $(this).val() + ',';
   });
   cities = cities.substr(0,cities.length-1);
   $('[name="city"]').remove();
   $('<input name="city" value="' + cities + '">').appendTo('form');
});
```

This will remove all of your city fields when they click submit, and add a new city field with the values in a comma seperated list.  You may need to attach it to the form submit action instead, but I'm not sure how jquery handles elements being added on the submit event.

Comment: wouldn't it be `implode()` if he's trying to go from an array (`city[]=1&city[]=2&city[]=3`) to a comma separated string (`city=1,2,3`)?

Comment: I was thinking he wanted them to send in a comma seperated string in the url, and now he needed to turn it into an array so he could use it in his app.  I could be mistaken.

Comment: Is it possible to send it in this format (city=1,2,3) from HTML Form?